# Check if two objects are not equal, unless they are both null

Tags: java, null, boolean-logic

The following Java snippet of code confuses me a bit. The method is trying to check whether two objects are **NOT** equal, using the standard `.equals()` method to denote that they are equal. Additionally, a boolean can determine whether two null's are considered equal or not. I'm wondering if:

- The boolean logic in this method is indeed correct?
- the `return` statement in the middle block can be omitted somehow. Could this logic be rewritten in a more concise or other way, maybe dropping the empty return, but keeping a high level of human readability of the code?

Snippet:

```
public static void verifyVariableIsNotEqualTo(Object variable, Object otherVariable, boolean considerBothNullAsEqual)
{
    if(considerBothNullAsEqual && variable == null && otherVariable == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("not allowed to be equal");
    }

    if(variable == null || otherVariable == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(variable.equals(otherVariable))
    {
        throw new Exception("not allowed to be equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev No, this code would not behave the same without the middle block.  If  `variable` were null, you would get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Incidentally, the method shown here doesn't actually compile, because it throws a checked exception, but doesn't declare it with a `throws` clause.

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev No, the OP's current code can NOT throw a `NullPointerException`, unless the `equals` method is written incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the logic in the method is correct.  It throws the exception if the two objects are equal.  You could remove the second condition and combine it with the third one, but I don't see much point.  If you did, the method might look like this.

```
public static void verifyVariableIsNotEqualTo(Object variable, Object otherVariable, boolean considerBothNullAsEqual) throws Exception
{
    if(considerBothNullAsEqual && variable == null && otherVariable == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("not allowed to be equal");
    }

    if(variable != null && variable.equals(otherVariable))
    {
        throw new Exception("not allowed to be equal");
    }
}
```

Note that there's no need to check whether `otherVariable` is null separately, since the `equals` method on `variable` should return false if `otherVariable` is null.

There's an even more concise way to write this, but it's not worth considering, since it sacrifices readability.